# Is it possible to extract a map AND separate variables from URL parameters using Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

```
public String myMethod(@RequestParam String param1, @RequestParam String param2, @RequestParam Map<String, String> map)
```

This is what I'm doing right now. It doesn't work properly though, because param1 and param2 are also present in the map. Is there any way around this? I'm using GET here, if it's of any help.

Answer (score 0):

Spring matrix variables may be obtained in a Map. But you need to send the url params as below.

```
// URL : GET /owners/42;q=11;r=12/pets/21;q=22;s=23

  @RequestMapping(value = "/owners/{ownerId}/pets/{petId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public void findPet(
    @MatrixVariable Map<String, String> matrixVars,
    @MatrixVariable(pathVar="petId"") Map<String, String> petMatrixVars) {    

// matrixVars: ["q" : [11,22], "r" : 12, "s" : 23]
// petMatrixVars: ["q" : 11, "s" : 23]
```

}

for more info refer: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-matrix-variables